# How do I convert a Pandoc Inline data type to a Blaze HTML data type

Tags: haskell, pandoc

Pandoc, when it parses a document, includes a metadata block.  The Title part of the metadata block is of type [Inline], a markup data type specific to Pandoc.  I am trying to find a way to convert that to Html so that I can embed that text directly into the Header element of an outgoing Html document.

What function, or combination of functions, is necessary to do this conversion?

```
[Inline] -> Html

[Str "My", Space, Str "Title"] -> ("My Title" :: Html)
```

- Inline is a data type for inline markup provided in Pandoc
- Html is the generic Html data type provided by Blaze Html

For the interim, I'm going to hack a function that handles Str and Space, but I know that I'm eventually going to need the way to do it that handles all of the Inline constructors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are only a few helper functions that I've found that come along Pandoc ([Data.Text.Pandoc.Shared](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pandoc/1.9.1.2/doc/html/Text-Pandoc-Shared.html#g:4) and by your example the `stringify` function would be all you need (this functions do note that it removes any formatting, which I guess is not important for text that goes into the header element).

```
inlineToHtml i = (Data.Text.Pandoc.Shared.stringify i) :: Html
```

Comment: Does this type-check? Isn't a call to [`string`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/blaze-markup/0.5.1.0/doc/html/Text-Blaze-Internal.html#v:string) also required? (i.e. `inlineToHtml = string . stringify`)

Comment: @dbaupp I've written the example based on OP's post. I have no experience with blaze html.

Answer (score 4):

What you want is this:

```
inlinesToHtml :: [Inline] -> Html
inlinesToHtml = writeHtml defaultWriterOptions . Plain
```